# Decoupling comments in javascript

Tags: javascript, comments, visual-studio-2013

Does anyone know if there are extensions that can "decouple" the comments from the code?  I envision a vertical split pane with a separate filename.ext.comments file.  See example image below.  Maybe that's crazy, so I will accept any recommendations for other ways to keep verbose, conceptual comments tidy.  (I am using XML type comments for functions to get intellisense, so I'm not worried about those).

[image]

Comment: Tangent: The first thing I'd do with any code like this is strip out all the comments. Comments lie and are a distraction. Here it is just a ton of noise. Are you sure you want to do this? If I have to comment something, it is a smell and I need to make my code cleaner so the comment can be removed.

Comment: use tabs for comments? Still less maintenance than spaces.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak:  They are tabs

Comment: @Cymenb: Are you serious? lol  Yes, I'm sure I want comments and I want them as verbose as possible.  They are stripped at build.  ANd your "distraction" point is exactly why I'm asking this question ;)

Comment: I am not sure why you have comments like this - they are simply repeating what the code already says. This is not very good use use of comments

Comment: @ScottBeeson if you have this many comments, you are probably overusing them. Comments serve as documentation, not as translation.

Comment: If you download web essentials: http://vswebessentials.com/ for VS2013 you can add regions to the code which enable you to minify comments as you need to.

Comment: With comments like this is it's too easy to read the correct behavior in the comments while glancing over the incorrect behavior in the actual code. The code and the comments are *inherently* decoupled.

Comment: Okay, I updated the OP.  Now with less terrifyingly verbose comments!

Comment: When everyone gives an answer that you don't want to hear, maybe it's that much more important that you hear it.  I apologize for piling on here, it's not for you, but for other innocents that may stumble on this question in the future.  _do not do this_.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with anyone, but I think it's an interesting point.  When learning to code, I remember getting "comment everything" drilled into my head.  I do some vbscript gigs on Fiverr and I always comment every single line so the buyer can adapt to his needs regardless of his skill level, I've had people explicitly thank me for it.  I suppose that is a nontypical situation, but I still find it interesting how pervasive this "you're commenting too much" response was.  I appreciate all the feedback though.